# IPC in C with named pipes

Tags: c, pipe, ipc, named-pipes

im trying to create two programs (A and B) in C. A sends an char array to B, B puts another char in the char array that he received from A and send it back to A. After A got the improved char array from B he will print it.

The problem is, i dont know how to tell A, that it should print it first when he received the improved char array back from B

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You probably need to define a protocol so that B knows when A is done sending, and so that A knows when B is done sending.  If you send the character arrays one character at a time, with a newline between them, then you could mark the end of the array by sending `"END\n"`.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you [include](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the relevant section of your code?

Comment: im new in stackoverflow, i wrote the code in the vim editor in shell, thats why i cant copy it and paste it here. I shoot a screen and uploaded it here: http://www2.pic-upload.de/img/30808319/Untitled.png

The other program just read the pipe and write the extended char array in it

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        // Here we use A and B as parent and child, made by fork
        // This allows us to pass pipe FDs
        int inpipe[2];
        int outpipe[2];
        pipe(inpipe);
        pipe(outpipe);
        const int arr_len = 4;
        const char buf[arr_len] = "ABD"; // Character [3] is implicit NUL
        int x = fork();
        if(x == -1) {
                perror("Fork error");
        }
        if(x == 0) {
                // Child
                char my_buf[arr_len];
                read(inpipe[0], my_buf, arr_len);
                // Improve it
                my_buf[2] = 'C'; // ABC looks better than ABD
                // Send it back
                write(outpipe[1], my_buf, arr_len);
                exit(0);
        }
        char my_buf[4];
        write(inpipe[1], buf, arr_len);
        // Will lock waiting for data
        read(outpipe[0], my_buf, arr_len);
        // Close pipes
        close(inpipe[0]);
        close(inpipe[1]);
        close(outpipe[0]);
        close(outpipe[1]);
        // Dump it
        printf("%s\n", my_buf);
        return 0;
}
```

Try to run this example, and see it sends the array between two processes. If one does not fork another, the only problem is to use named pipes (replace `pipe` call with `mkfifo` call, and some other changes). Feel free to base on this example. Also look at this:

```
int ifd = mypipe[0], ofd = mypipe[1]; // mypipe is got somewhere before
FILE *istream = fdopen(ifd, "r"), ostream = fdopen(ofd, "w");
// Now use any stdio functions on istream and ostream
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jakub, i will try it once im home on my laptop. When i want do to this in 2 different process's, do i only need to export the child block in the other function? Then i need to run A for char array, then B to write it back, then A again to print the result

Comment: Yes. Also mind that the part with `int[2]`s is possible only on `fork`ed process. To use it between two independent processes, you need named pipes (or Linux `procfs`). See man pages: `pipe(2)`, `mkfifo(1)`, `mkfifo(3)`. In procfs, to access other process's FDs as normal files, use path: `/proc/<PID>/fd/<FD>`.